# Can Spring boot dynamically create end points based on the content of the property file?

Tags: java, spring, rest

**So far I am creating end points like this:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String indexPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
//Doing calculations
return "Result";
}
```

But I would like to reach the application.properties when the server starts, to read out the data stored like this:

```
methods: {
"endpointOne": "DBStoredProcedure1",
"endpointTwo": "DBStoredProcedure2"
}
```

So **when my Spring Boot application starts, it would create all the POST endpoints based on the property file** with the names of the first parameters (like "endpointOne"), and would call (and return the result of) the stored procedure which is defined as the second parameter (like "DBStoredProcedure1").

**Is it possible to do?**

Comment: I think not. But to simplify your work you could take a look at swagger: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes you can. A little bit differently though than you try to do it at the moment.

The best is to use a "PathVariable" - you find detailed information here:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/

http://javabeat.net/spring-mvc-requestparam-pathvariable/

Your method at the Controller class would look something like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/{endPoint}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String endPoint(@PathVariable String endPoint) {
   //Your endPoint is now the one what the user would like to reach
   //So you check if your property file contains this String - better to cache it's content
   //If it does, you call the service with the regarding Stored Procedure.
   String sPName = prop.getSPName(endPoint); //You need to implement it.
   String answer = yourService.execute(sPName);
   return answer; 
 }
```

Obviously you need to implement a method to handle those queries which are not found in the property file, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a charm.

Comment: Mind giving a full example? I'm new to spring.

Comment: Especially how would you raise a 404 if the endpoint does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wild card "/*" as the value in controller. So that all your endpoints would hit the same controller request method.

Below is the code sample.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=*/*", produces = { "application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getData(@RequestParam Map<String, String> reqParam, HttpServletRequest request)
            throws WriteException, IOException{

        MessageLogger.infoLog(EquityControllerImpl.class, GETQADTRSTOCKPRICELOGS,
                ENTRY);

        // Get Request URI
        MessageLogger.infoLog("Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
        String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();


        //Read all request parameters
        Map<String, String> requestParamMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param: reqParam.entrySet()
             ) {
            System.out.println("Parameter: " + param.getKey() + " ----> Value: " + param.getValue());
            requestParamMap.put(param.getKey(),param.getValue());
        }
}
```

Also you can define static swagger.json and use this in the swagger configuration.

```
    @Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(SpringDataRestConfiguration.class)
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.finance.dataplatform.*"))
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(getApiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Investment Management").build();
    }

    private static Predicate<String> matchPathRegex(final String... pathRegexs) {
        return new Predicate<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(String input) {
                for (String pathRegex : pathRegexs) {
                    if (input.matches(pathRegex)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/config/swagger.json")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/config");
            }
        };
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean
    public SwaggerResourcesProvider swaggerResourcesProvider(InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider defaultResourcesProvider) {
        return () -> {
            SwaggerResource wsResource = new SwaggerResource();
            wsResource.setName("default");
            wsResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
            wsResource.setLocation("/config/swagger.json");

            //List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>(defaultResourcesProvider.get());
            List<SwaggerResource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
            resources.add(wsResource);
            return resources;
        };
    }
}
```