# Spring boot: How to pass a command line argument into an annotation value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
@SpringBootApplication public class App {
    public static final String NAME;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired public App(ApplicationArguments arguments) {
        NAME = arguments.getSourceArgs()[0]; // ERROR (1)
    }

    @GetMapping("/" + NAME) public void test() { // ERROR (2)
        return NAME;
    }
}
```

The code doesn't work as written because (1) `NAME` cannot be assigned, and (2) annotation value for `@GetMapping` must be a constant expression.

I just want `@GetMapping` to use a value based on a command line argument. How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Spring boot dynamically create end points based on the content of the property file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41360048/can-spring-boot-dynamically-create-end-points-based-on-the-content-of-the-proper)

Comment: For the ERROR (1), you should not claim the variable NAME to be final (static is OK.), or you cannot change its value.

Answer (score 0):

in the first request. spring mvc will init the resource. so your put your dynamic url in haddlermapping.

we need three classes. `MyController` `MyDispatcherServlet` `DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration`

MyController.java

```
@Component(value="MyController")
public class MyController {

@Autowired
ClaimService claimService;

public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> insertClaim() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

MyDispatcherServlet.java. after initStrategies.put, your dynamic url into handdlerMapping.

```
public class MyDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

private String url;


public MyDispatcherServlet(String url) {
    super();
    this.url = url;
}


@Override
protected void onRefresh(ApplicationContext context) {
    initStrategies(context);
    List<HandlerMapping> handlerMappings = getHandlerMappings();
    for (HandlerMapping handlerMapping : handlerMappings) {

        if (handlerMapping instanceof RequestMappingHandlerMapping) {
            RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping = ((RequestMappingHandlerMapping) handlerMapping);
            RequestMappingInfo.Builder n = RequestMappingInfo
                    .paths(url)
                    .methods(RequestMethod.GET);
            try {
                Method method = MyController.class.getDeclaredMethod("insertClaim");
                requestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping(n.build(), "MyController", method);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}


}
```

DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherServletCustomConfiguration {

@Value("${myUrl}")
private String url;

@Bean
public DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet() {
    return new MyDispatcherServlet(url);
   }

}
```

run with the command `java -jar stackoverflow-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar  --myUrl=abcd`